# How to fetch stock price from Australia Stock Exchange

Tags: stockquotes

How can I fetch a stock's price from the Australian Stock Exchange (ASX): www.asx.com.au/

Actually our team is working on a corporate site which would be listed soon at Australian Stock Exchange. I need to display details about the stock (including the price) on the home page. How can I do this?

Do stock exchanges provide data feeds? If so, how do I access these feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that talking to ASX is going to be the way to go. They'll *certainly* provide you with real time information, but at a price.

Answer (score 2):

ASX must have an API. But there seem to be some options such as [RSS Feeds](http://noisymime.org/asx/). Live feeds are not free, free feeds are 20minutes delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Finance offer a delayed service (15 mins) on ASX listed companies. You could also fetch it with a screen scrape of google finance (also delayed). Since you are not yet listed it may take a while before either pick up your symbol. I believe both get their data from csinitiative which is a pay-for service. I'm not sure what programming language you are using but the Yahoo service certainly has many libraries already built in python/ruby/java.

Answer (score -1):

Getting data from Yahoo is straight forward.

Here's a link for MSFT: http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT

To get data for the ASX add .AX to the end of the code, eg

http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MPL.AX

I've written an article about about acquiring and graphing stock market data:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1069489/Highstock-plus-Data-Forge-plus-Yahoo

Comment: This service has been discontinued.

Comment: Yes most annoyingly Yahoo has terminated their stock APIs.

I'm using Alpha Vantage these days, here's a blog post about it:

http://www.the-data-wrangler.com/acquiring-stock-market-data-from-alpha-vantage/

Comment: In response to @AshleyDavis comment, Alpha Vantage now no longer supports ASX, or a variety of other markets for that matter, they have scaled back their service significantly.

Comment: For anyone after a good data source try https://eodhistoricaldata.com/. That's what I'm using these days, It's a paid service, but pretty reasonable. It's easy to use.  And it does all the exchanges, crypto and probably other markets.

Answer (score -6):

Adding an ".AX" at the end of each of stocks enabled me to get the data:

`stock_list = ["ANZ.AX", "WBC.AX", "CBA.AX", "QAN.AX", "WOW.AX"]`

Comment: from what source?

Comment: Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979376/4504945), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AusFinance/comments/8pr6hj/has_anyone_found_an_api_for_batch_asx_shareprices/), [here](https://www.aussiestockforums.com/threads/pyress-a-python-interface-to-iress.20972/), & [here](https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/28457/extracting-all-historical-companies-listed-on-the.html)